# DC Chopper Operation in SMES Design

Tags: inductor, electromagnetic, igbt

I'm reading a paper on a superconducting magnetic energy storage (SMES) power control system. One large superconducting inductor (L1 in the figure below) is charged up by a 10kA power supply. Once charged, L1 is isolated from the power supply (Sw1a & Sw1b are switched off) and connected to the DC chopper circuit with switches Sw2a & Sw2b. The chopper circuit transfers the energy to SMES inductor L2 with a switching frequency of 300Hz. The energy is then stored in L2 or transferred back to L1 again with the chopper circuit. This serves as a demonstration of transferring energy between SMES systems.

I’m confused with how the DC chopper operates specifically. I’ve tried to picture different switching scenarios where one or two IGBTs are off and the others are open. What is the order of how the switches S1, S2, S3, and S4 are operated in the attached figure? Is the purpose of the chopper is to split up the DC output and isolate L1 from L2 so all the energy from L1 can be transferred to L2? For reference the paper is "Energy Transfer Experiments between 3 and 4 MJ Pulsed Superconducting Magnets" by T. Onishi, 1985. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If the inductor coil L1 is charged and then isolated from the supply and then the power transfer happens from L1 to L2, the switches S1 and S2 has to undergo PWM to provide controlled output current from L1 to L2. Meanwhile, the switches S3 and S4 are off and the charging circuit for L2 is completed as: L1->S2->D4->L2->D3->S1->L1. The capacitor C has been employed to forward bias the IGBT S3 and simultaneously S4 during the charing cycle of L2. It is charged when the switches S1 and S2 are off, through the loop: L1->D1->C->D2->L1.

Answer (score 0):

Observe this from [LTC3780 buck boost converter datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3780.pdf):

[image]

Your circuit is the dual of this one, with voltage and current swapped.

The one above transfers energy between input and output capacitors which during one cycle can be approximated as constant voltage power supplies. It uses an inductor as the "bucket" that transfers one bucketful of energy from one end to the other every cycle.

Yours transfers energy between input and output inductors which can be approximated as constant current power supplies. It uses a capacitor as the "bucket".

Basically if you have two capacitors charged at different voltages you can't connect them in parallel because a huge current would flow. So a component that limits rate of rise of current (the inductor) and stores energy is used in between.

And if you have two inductors charged at different currents you can't connect them in series because that would cause voltage to rise until something breaks. So a component that limits rate of rise of **voltage** (the capacitor) and stores energy is used in between.

It's the same, in a mirror, swapping current for voltage, series for parallel, and L for C.

Charge up inductor L1.

Open SW1a,b

Inductor L1 current flows through D1,C,D2 charging capacitor C. Wait a bit until its voltage rises to desired value.

Turn on thyristors S1 or S2 (not both). Suppose you turn on S2. L1 current flows through S2, D2. L1 is shorted (minus drop voltage from thyristor and diode) and it is now off circuit.

Capacitor C is still charged. Turn on S3, S4. C discharges into L2, so L2 current increases. Wait until the cap has been discharged enough that L2 current stops increasing, and turn off S3,S4.

L2 current is now looping through D3 D4.

Repeat, until enough energy has been transferred from L1 to L2.

That was the simplified version. For better efficiency, it is possible (and advisable) to overlap the on-times of thyristors on the left and the right, so the voltage on capacitor C becomes a sawtooth like the current in a buck-boost inductor. In fact, thyristors and diodes have constant ON drop voltage, which means the best efficiency should happen when loss-causing voltage across diodes and thyristors is smallest relative to useful voltage across C. So this should be operated with C close to its maximum allowed voltage, with an algorithm pretty much identical to the one in the LTC3780 (datasheet page 13).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### Observations

- [this power source is proof of concept dual-chopper type DCDC converter.](https://www.electrical4u.com/chopper-dc-to-dc-converter/)
- It starts with a super high current source of 10kA going into a large magnet coil of size (?) of L (?) with high current flyback diodes across it in efforts to regulate very high DC currents by regulating the intermediate boosted AC voltage into a non-linear DC negative resistance arc fusion reactor.
- Both bridges are composed of **2 high current diodes diagonally opposite to 2 GTO (gate turn-off) Thyristors.**
- Somewhat like normal thyristors except may be turned off with -5V
  (slowish) and turned on very fast with current pulses >1.2 V.

  - These are  probably the type with a thousand parallel PNPN junctions in parallel to support the high current and perhaps the size of a hockey puck. (Invented by GE)
- the result is supposed to be a boosted flyback voltage with alternating Gate Turn-Off’s while the other GTO is on.
- The diodes catch the flyback current and charge the 38mF capacitor.
- The Vcap is monitored as negative feedback to regulate the alternating pulse width and deadtime phases for the complementary GTO’s
- the 2nd bridge is similar except performing as another synchronous chopper ( performance unknown TL;DR article).
- But as a dual synchronous chopper is known to convert a baseband or DC signal AC coupled back to DC.
- In this case it is a power signal with a 10kA source from a fusion reactor with a DC output potentially with higher voltage at lower current as the source here is a superconductor.

————-

Background
~
This experimental power supply says in the abstract , (which was (all ) I had access to) that it was for a superconductor  lines to an Ohmic heater of a Fusion Reactor for a short high temp test.

> “ energy transfer experiments between a 3 MJ magnet (load magnet) and a 4 MJ magnet energy storage magnet) using a chopper-type energy transfer equipment. The test goal was to confirm the technical feasibility of operating an ohmic heating coil for a tokamak-type fusion reactor. A 3 MJ magnet was first charged to 4510 amperes in 1. 5 seconds. It was discharged to 0 ampere in 1. 5 seconds and at once was re-charged to minus 4510 amperes in 1. 5 seconds. It was again discharged in 1. 5 seconds”

The quad or full bridges switch on the high side and can be PWM modulated on Lo side. they are identified as choppers which amplitude modulate a carrier with the DC input. I suspect this is for a **buck** voltage for a DCDC converter of exceptionally high power to provide higher (!) output current for the arc heater of a potential fusion reactor.

Energy is stored in series and shunt to regulate the power with feedback on voltage and current regulate the output.= load.  (See any buck-boost regulator paper such as the one below from PSIM examples for detailed operations. These are not the correct values that need to be scaled down towards the impedance of the superconductor impedance.

Using two such full-wave bridges doubles the voltage at 4x the power in a differential mode.  It used the FLyback-effect with the experiment using 1.5s half-cycle time **for two cycles only,** due to the immense heat and need to regulate it was terminated as a proof of concept.